# Which programs can break subroutines on a trap?

Tags: android-netrunner

If I Rez a trap (eg: [Howler](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03016)) which programs can break subroutines on it? Is it just AI like [Crypsis](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01051) or are there others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Traps generally do not have one of the 3 usual subtypes (Barrier, Code Gate, or Sentry). So they cannot be broken by breakers for those types of ice. In general you need an AI breaker like Crypsis, [Overmind](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/honor-and-profit/overmind-honor-and-profit), [Knight](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/the-spin-cycle/mala-tempora/knight-mala-tempora), or any of the other AI breakers. However traps can still be bypassed with [Femme](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/core/femme-fatale-core), just like any other ice.

Note that some traps DO have a breakable subtypes. Such as [data mine](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/core/data-mine-core). Because this trap is AP it can be broken with [Deus Ex](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/netrunner/android-netrunner-card-spoilers/_/genesis/a-study-in-static/deus-x-a-study-in-static).

Comment: At the time of the posting of this answer, data mine was the only ice breakable by non AI means, no other traps had ice subtypes that any breakers mentioned. There is now a trap, [Sandstorm](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/12114) that is big enough to be broken by [D4v1d](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/06033). [Mganga](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/21013) is now a second AP trap. Other than those three it's AI breakers only for traps.